# Adding class to parent using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

span click `<p>` color change

```css
span:focus~.to-be-changed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="to-be-changed">I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...</p>
<span tabindex="0">Click me!</span>
```

I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...

Click me!

Answer (score 3):

The `~` refers to all the siblings after the element. In your example the `.to-be-changed` is a previous sibling. You can place them in the order you need in the dom and then reorder them using `flex` and `order`

```css
span:focus~.to-be-changed {
  color: red;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .to-be-changed{
  order: 1;
}

.container span{
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span tabindex="0">Click me!</span>
  <p class="to-be-changed">I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.parent {display: flex;}
span { order: 2;}
.to-be-changed {order: 1;}
span:active~.to-be-changed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span tabindex="0">Click me!</span>
<p class="to-be-changed">I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...</p>
</div>
```

So far (Feb.2019) you cannot select parent of an element, or the previous sibling of an element.

But you can do a css trick to place the `<p>` element after `<span>` element in html but display the `<p>` element before `span` element. Then you can achieve the goal. The snippet above is an example, if you need to support old browser you can also use `float:right;` instead.

However, in the future, we will have ':has()' css selector which will allow us to select parent of an element. Here you can check this selector info [:has() selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).